# Changing Column of several dataframes based on each dataframe's column's value

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

Suppose I have about 180 different dataframes looking like this with columns ID, x, it, st. Now I would like to change the st column so that the new value is **st-1 for all dataframes**. So the output for example for this dataframe in the first 9 rows remains NA, from row 10 onwards it would be 11.0.

This dataframe for example is called control37868.So the column to be changed is control37868$st

```
ID    x           it         st
2    1.464462e+12 20.17831   NA
3    1.464462e+12 20.15657   NA
4    1.464463e+12 20.13484   NA
5    1.464463e+12 20.11310   NA
6    1.464464e+12 20.09136   NA
7    1.464465e+12 20.06963   NA
8    1.464465e+12 20.04789   NA
9    1.464466e+12 20.02615   NA
10   1.464466e+12 20.00442 12.0
11   1.464467e+12 19.98268 12.0
12   1.464468e+12 19.96094 12.0
13   1.464468e+12 19.93921 12.0
14   1.464469e+12 19.95700 12.0
15   1.464469e+12 20.01383 12.0
16   1.464470e+12 19.96272 12.0
17   1.464471e+12 19.96149 12.0
18   1.464471e+12 20.01166 12.0
19   1.464472e+12 19.92711 12.0
20   1.464472e+12 19.90119 12.0
21   1.464473e+12 19.88064 12.0
22   1.464474e+12 19.86010 12.0
```

I already created a list with all dataframes in it:

```
#get list with all dataframes
dflist <- list(incident11951, incident12720, incident13643, incident1379, incident14248, incident14968, incident15634, incident16439, incident17383, incident17734, incident17850, incident18009, incident18337, incident21888, incident22666, incident23269, incident23682, incident23870, incident24493, incident25116, incident25669, incident26222, incident26931, incident28226, incident28290, incident29070, incident29180, incident29484, incident29726, incident29969, incident30244, incident30691, incident30967, incident31376, incident31434, incident32608, incident33041, incident33668, incident35112, incident35254, incident35577, incident36125, incident36267, incident36592, incident36671, incident37244, incident37412, incident37724, incident37868, incident38161, incident39453, incident39786, incident40482, incident40487, incident40975, incident41013, incident41381, incident41701, incident41772, incident42226, incident42358, incident42613, incident43395, incident43476, incident44827, incident45053, incident45454, incident45605, incident45703, incident46637, incident47832, incident50133, incident52105, incident5585, incident56003, incident56862, incident58213, incident58960, incident617, incident6361, incident7122, incident8144, incident9027, incident9245, incident9262, incident9534, incident9875, control11951, control12720, control13643, control1379, control14248, control14968, control15634, control16439, control17383, control17734, control17850, control18009, control18337, control21888, control22666, control23269, control23682, control23870, control24493, control25116, control25669, control26222, control26931, control28226, control28290, control29070, control29180, control29484, control29726, control29969, control30244, control30691, control30967, control31376, control31434, control32608, control33041, control33668, control35112, control35254, control35577, control36125, control36267, control36592, control36671, control37244, control37412, control37724, control37868, control38161, control39453, control39786, control40482, control40487, control40975, control41013, control41381, control41701, control41772, control42226, control42358, control42613, control43395, control43476, control44827, control45053, control45454, control45605, control45703, control46637, control47832, control50133, control52105, control5585, control56003, control56862, control58213, control58960, control617, control6361, control7122, control8144, control9027, control9245, control9262, control9534, control9875)
```

This should be doable with the sapply() function over the dflist but I am not sure how to define the right function that changes the column values depending on the current value.

It would also be ok to just add that column and name it threshold. Therefore I also tried

```
 Map(cbind, dflist, threshold = st-1)
```

but the reference of st-1 is obviouly not sufficient

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

```
dflist<- lapply(dflist, function(x){
          y <- x[!is.na(x$st),]; 
          y$st <- y$st-1; 
          x[!is.na(x$st),] <- y; 
          x})
```

If you want to change a single dataframe df you could try:

```
idx <- which(!is.na(df$st)) 
if (length(idx) > 0) df[idx, ]$st <- df[idx,]$st-1
```

Comment: One could do this too. `lapply(l, function(x){ y=x ; y$st <- y$st-1; y})`

Comment: Great; thank you! This applied the function to the list with the dataframes. However, when I now call the single dataframes, the column didn't change. Is there a way to transfer the changes from the list with the dataframes to the actual dataframes?

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I would like to change all dataframes. The first way worked (thank you!), but only for the list. Is there a way to transfer this to **all** dataframes? So that they change as well? I also have a second question; how would I add a column to all dataframes with the difference of st-it if it<st? Thank you for your help!